# reading res.json in nodejs app

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a simple nodejs get that runs like this:

```
app.get('/customer/:ent_cust_id', function (req, res, next) {
        var query = 'Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ' + req.params.ent_cust_id;
        console.log('Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id =' + req.params.ent_cust_id);
        client.execute(query, function (err, result) {
        if (err) return next (err);
        var row = result.rows[0];
            if (result.rows.length==0) {
                res.send('ent_cust_id: ' + req.params.ent_cust_id + ' not found. Not all data is loaded.');
        } else {
            var row = result.rows[0];
                //Response
                res.json({ent_cust_id: req.params.ent_cust_id, accts: row.get('accts'), offers: row.get('offers')});
        };
        });
 });
```

and will return a result into an array like this:

```
{"ent_cust_id":"1013686356",
        "accts":{
            "3017":{"popn_typ_cd":"CNSMR_DIRCT_CHKG","prod_type_cd":"DDA","ent_prod_cd":"CNSDD","curr_amt":"14.67","bal_90_days":null,"region":"NULL","trst_acct_ind":0,"legal_ind":0,"emp_acct_ind":1,"mnor_ind":0},
            "2752":{"popn_typ_cd":"CNSMR_LENDG","prod_type_cd":"MLA","ent_prod_cd":"CNSML","curr_amt":null,"bal_90_days":null,"region":"NULL","trst_acct_ind":0,"legal_ind":0,"emp_acct_ind":1,"mnor_ind":1},
            "888":{"popn_typ_cd":"CNSMR_DIRCT_MORT","prod_type_cd":"MLA","ent_prod_cd":"CNSML","curr_amt":null,"bal_90_days":null,"region":"NULL","trst_acct_ind":0,"legal_ind":0,"emp_acct_ind":1,"mnor_ind":0}
            },
        "offers":{
            "5998":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-06-03T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"Statement Message","channel":"LIST","campaign":"STMT_MESSAGE","campaign_tp":"STATEMENT"},
            "6998":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-07-03T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"Statement Message","channel":"LIST","campaign":"STMT_MESSAGE","campaign_tp":"STATEMENT"},
            "7998":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-08-03T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"Statement Message","channel":"LIST","campaign":"STMT_MESSAGE","campaign_tp":"STATEMENT"},
            "506A":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-06-18T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"Availability CIT","channel":"EM","campaign":"FUNDS_AVAILABILITY_CIT","campaign_tp":"NOTIFICATION"},
            "06_A":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-06-29T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"Mob5X","channel":"EM","campaign":"EMAIL","campaign_tp":"UPSELL"},
            "5009":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-06-05T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"e Reminder","channel":"EM","campaign":"STMT_REMINDER","campaign_tp":"STATEMENT"},
            "6009":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-07-09T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"e Reminder","channel":"EM","campaign":"STMT_REMINDER","campaign_tp":"STATEMENT"},
            "7996":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-08-10T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"e Reminder","channel":"EM","campaign":"STMT_REMINDER","campaign_tp":"STATEMENT"},
            "R_33S":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-08-10T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"1Offer","channel":"DM","campaign":"TIERED CASH AUG SEP","campaign_tp":"SELL"},
            "R_34S":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2025-12-31T05:00:00.000Z","creative":"1Offer","channel":"DM","campaign":"TIERED CASH AUG SEP","campaign_tp":"SELL"},
            "R_22":{"contacted":"Y","hit_home_date":"2015-06-22T04:00:00.000Z","creative":"1Offer","channel":"EM","campaign":"TIERED CASH","campaign_tp":"SELL"}
            }
    }
```

I see how I can get the first level of the array, but what if I want to get any other part of the array.

What if I also want to check if in `offers`, the `contacted` field is marked as `Y` at all in any of the results in teh offers part?

How do I do that?

EDIT:

seems like this is just a string and not an array. So maybe the question then is, how do I transform this into an array and/or json object?

Comment: to be clear, there are no arrays in your output, that's just an object. Getting the 2nd and 3rd level is no different from getting the first. `data.offers['5998'].contacted` to get the first.

Comment: Your query also appears to be vulnerable to sql injection, fyi. if param equaled `1;delete from entcustinfo` you might have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First-off, I don't see any arrays, so I'm a little confused about the first question?

But in answer to your second question, if your data has been evaluated into an object called 'data', which is an array of the above JSON, you could do:

```
var custId = "1013686356";
var determineIfContacted = function(custId, data) {
    var customers = data.filter(function(item) { return item.ent_cust_id == custId; })
    var customer = customers[0]; // you should validate that you have a matching customer here
    var hasBeenContacted = false;
    foreach (var offerId in customer.offers) {
        if (customer.offers[offerId].contacted === "Y") {
            hasBeenContacted = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return hasBeenContacted;
}
```

Hope this helps (: